# Using Deployment Centre for Azure Web App with Javascript .NET Core 7 / BitBucket Repo

Tags: javascript, bitbucket

[Picture of Deployment Centre in the Azure Web App portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHGS5.jpg)

We are using the Deployment Centre in the Azure Web App portal, to link our BitBucket repo.

When this is built, the javascript libraries do not seem to be created.

The app (that has been built in .NET Core 7) does not copy the ../SCRIPTS/ folders to Azure.

We have tried adding some solutions such as:

```
<ItemGroup>
     <Content Include="wwwroot\SCRIPTS\**\*.*">
          <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
     </Content>
</ItemGroup>

<Folder Include="wwwroot\SCRIPTS\" />
```

This works for the code until we make any further commits, at which point the changes are not built.

We have another project built in .NET Core 7 with KnockoutJS and exactly the same issue occurs.

Deploying the code should include the JS libraries.